# Cannot find symbol androidx.annotation.NonNull

Tags: java, android, gradle

In my Android app I have

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.0"
}
```

in `build.gradle` and

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

In my Java code.

If I change Billing version to 4.0.0 as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"
}
```

my Java code stops compiling and I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
```

How to fix this?

I tried to add

```
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0"
```

to `build.gradle`, but it does not help.

In my `gradle.properties` I have this:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**EDIT1**

I am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.settingslib.media.MediaDevice.isConnected()' on a null object reference" with my new version that depends on billing v6:

```
Exception Process: com.android.settings, PID: 20342
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.settingslib.media.MediaDevice.isConnected()' on a null object reference
  at com.android.settingslib.media.MediaDevice.compareTo (MediaDevice.java:325)
  at com.android.settingslib.media.MediaDevice.compareTo (MediaDevice.java:56)
  at java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator.compare (Comparators.java:52)
  at java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator.compare (Comparators.java:47)
  at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending (TimSort.java:355)
  at java.util.TimSort.sort (TimSort.java:220)
  at java.util.Arrays.sort (Arrays.java:1492)
  at java.util.ArrayList.sort (ArrayList.java:1470)
  at java.util.Collections.sort (Collections.java:206)
  at com.android.settingslib.media.LocalMediaManager$MediaDeviceCallback.onDeviceListAdded (LocalMediaManager.java:484)
  at com.android.settingslib.media.MediaManager.dispatchDeviceListAdded (MediaManager.java:91)
  at com.android.settingslib.media.InfoMediaManager.refreshDevices (InfoMediaManager.java:407)
  at com.android.settingslib.media.InfoMediaManager.access$000 (InfoMediaManager.java:61)
  at com.android.settingslib.media.InfoMediaManager$RouterManagerCallback.onRoutesAdded (InfoMediaManager.java:514)
  at android.media.MediaRouter2Manager.lambda$notifyRoutesAdded$0 (MediaRouter2Manager.java:671)
  at android.media.MediaRouter2Manager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.run
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: Is your version downgrade really necessary ?

Comment: @ItzDavi I do not know, I am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.settingslib.media.MediaDevice.isConnected()' on a null object reference" with my new version that depends on billing v6.

Comment: Update your question with the code causing the error and the error itself, I will provide more support!

Comment: @ItzDavi it is not my code, see the stack trace.

Answer (score -2):

The error is straight forward to the point.

> java.lang.**NullPointerException**: **Attempt to invoke virtual method** 'boolean com.android.settingslib.media.MediaDevice.isConnected()' **on a null object reference**

This means you are trying to check for a boolean value in a null object reference. Without the code causing the error I can't help you more.

See [the migration guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv6) to check if everything is correctly setup in the project.

I commented before asking if the version downgrade is really necessary since the migration guide has a **Reminder** at the top:

> Starting on August 2, 2023, all new apps must use Billing Library version 5 or newer. By November 1, 2023, all updates to existing apps must use Billing Library version 5 or newer.

Please let me know if you need more support, happy coding!